# AngularJS : Load defer JSON and Use It between multiple Controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, controller

Sirs, I have a problem with AngularJS...

I'm trying to load a JSON file in promise, and use it with two controller different... I tried a lot of different technics, but I don't get it... Could you help me?

```
//SERVICE
app.service('AllPosts', function($http, $q){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('posts.json').then(function(data){
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    this.getPosts = function(){
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    this.getPost = function(id){
        var post={};
        angular.forEach(deferred.promise, function(value) {
            if(value.id == id){
                post=value;
            }
        });
        return post;
    };
});
```

I'm creating a service to call the JSON and in the same way I declare my functions for my controllers...

```
app.controller('AllCtrl', function($scope, AllPosts){   
    AllPosts.getPosts().then(function(posts){
        $scope.posts = posts.data;
    });
});
```

In my first controller I call the function getPosts to obtain all the posts from my JSON...

```
app.controller('PostCtrl', function($scope, AllPosts, $routeParams) {
    AllPosts.getPost($routeParams.id).then(function(the_post){
        $scope.comments = post.comments;
        $scope.title = post.name; 
        $scope.the_content = post.content;
    });
});
```

In this second controller, I only want one of the posts, so I call the function getPost...

But I don't have any idea how to do, in the first case it works with all posts, but in the second, nope... I'm new with Angular and if you have other methods, it would be great too!
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

To make your `getPost()` work the way you have things now would need to do:

```
this.getPost = function(id) {
  // return same promise
  return deferred.promise.then(function(posts) {
    // but return only one post
    var post = {};
    angular.forEach(posts, function(value) {
      if (value.id == id) {
        post = value;
      }
    });
    return post;

  })

};
```

However `$http` itself returns  promise so you don't need `$` at all

```
app.service('AllPosts', function($http) {

  var postsPromise = $http.get('posts.json').then(function(response) {
    return response.data
  });
  this.getPosts = function() {
    return postsPromise;
  };
  this.getPost = function(id) {
    // return same promise
    return postsPromise.then(function(posts) {
      // but return only one post
      var post = {};
      angular.forEach(posts, function(value) {
        if (value.id == id) {
          post = value;
        }
      });
      return post;

    })

  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can't make it work, don't know why, but I will look closer... Thanks ;) Oh by the way, carefull with postsPromise and postPromise :)

Comment: any errors in console? Need to isolate what is or isn't working

Comment: No i didn't have any error, but I use $q to make a defer and it works now for all the posts, not for only one... :/

Answer (score 0):

You're basically nearly there, you just have some placement/ordering issues with your code. In order for you to be able to call `AllPosts.getPosts()` in each controller, you will need to make a few adjustments to your service.

Firstly, you should change your service to a factory. Factories are [singletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), whereas services have an instance invoked for each call/injection almost like classes/objects using the `new` operator.
This is just so that you can have a consistent set of values across all your controllers, without wasting resources instantiating a new service for each controller. They will all share the same one.

Secondly, you just need to make a few changes to the promise/deferrer pattern. See below:

```
// Factory - REMEMBER TO INCLUDE LODASH
app.factory('AllPosts', function($http, $q){
    var self = {};
    // create a private posts array to store the cached values
    // The reason for making it private is to prevent you from 
    // directly accessing it rather than using the getter function,
    // potentially giving you the wrong/old values;
    var posts = [];
    var expiry = null;
    self.getPosts = function(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var currentTimeStamp = new Date.getTime();
      // if we have a cached value, that hasn't expired, 
      //get that instead of making another http call
      if(self.posts.length > 0 && currentTimeStamp !== null &&
         currentTimeStamp < expiry) {
        deferred.resolve(self.posts);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
      $http.get('posts.json').then(function(data){
        // cache the values to remove the 
        // need for multiple $http calls
        expiry = new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 5) // expire in 5 minutes
        posts = data;
        deferred.resolve(data);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    };
    self.getPost = function(id){
      // Use lodash to simplify your life :)
      return _.find(posts, {id: id});
    }
    return self;
});
```

I would highly recommend libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to help you if you are going to do a lot of collection/array manipulation and/or iteration.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your changes... I'll try this later. I'm learning Angular so I was trying not adding any other libraries, but I will look closer at Lodash... Thanks. And the thing is that I already did a factory and I wanted to learn services, but I understand ah ah

Comment: No worries, angular can be a bit of a fickle beast at times! Strangely in the few years I've been using it I've rarely had to use a service instead of a factory, but good that you're trying new things!